# Plot plotted inside the ipython console

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am working in python and using Anaconda with Spyder and I need to plot a scatter plot in a part of the code I am working on. The plot is just fine but is drawn in the console itself and the size is quite small for my needs.

My question is, how can I plot it in another window outside the ipython console? I already tried changing some of the setting like changing Graphics setting in ipython from inline to QT to tkinter. Nothing seems to work.

Any helpful suggestions?

Comment: are you using ipython notebook ?

Comment: starting a session with `%matplotlib qt` does the trick for me.

Comment: @sachinsaxena : no i'm just using Spyder with ipython console.

Comment: @cel: thanks for the solution. But I would have to do that every time I start a python session. It doesn't seem to work if I include that at the beginning of the script. Is there a way I can change the settings permanently or include it in the script.

Answer (score 0):

you can just save %matplotlib qt in a .py file and you can start ipython using:

```
    ipython -i myfile.py
```